# Google Apps Script / Slack - async or a quick response

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, v8, slack, slack-api

I'm building a Slack App for staff doing daily checkins. Staff checkin using the `/checkin` slash command in Slack. Slack requires a response to the slash command within 3 seconds. If it doesn't then it gives an operation_timeout error to the person who initiated the command.

In my setup the slash command fails the first time for every user, but always works the second time. Rather than rely on this issue going away, is there a way to make sure that the script responds within 3 seconds? Google Apps Script seems a bit slow with it. Even returning a simple response seems slow.

Can I return a quick response to Slack first, and then process the data afterwards? It seems my logUser function is taking longer to execute than the 3s. Or can it be run in a non-blocking way? But even with that, it does seem the response is unreasonably slow.

```html
function doPost(request){
    var params = request.parameters;
    var user = params.user_id;
    var text = params.text;

    if(text == ''){
      logUser(user);
      return ContentService.createTextOutput(':white_check_mark: Checked In! Thank you! <@' + user + '> ');
    } 
}
```

Edit: I think I can use `ScriptApp.newTrigger("logUser").timeBased().after(200).create();` to delay the running of logUser, to allow the message to be returned to Slack early. But then I lose the ability to give a parameter to the logUser function?

Edit: `logUser` function as requested

```html
function logUser(user){
    var checkinSheet = getTodaySheet();
    var name = getNameFromId(user);
    var date = new Date();
    var time = date.getTime();

    checkinSheet.appendRow([name, user[0], "TRUE"]);
}
```

logUser is selecting the correct Google Sheet (we have one for every day), checking the SlackID of the person who initiated the Slack command against an employee spreadsheet, finding the name of the person who initiated it, and then posting that name into the correct Google Sheet. This can be time consuming, so I can understand why this blocks the response.

Can logUser be run after returning the response to Slack?

Comment: Can you show your `logUser()` function?

Comment: @RafaGuillermo Added. It does take time to execute. I think I need to be able to run it after returning the message to Slack. Not sure how though.

Comment: Is it likely that multiple people will log in at the same, or approximately the same time? Also, how much leeway do you have on the recorded log-in times?

Comment: @RafaGuillermo It is highly likely that many people will run the script around the same time.

Lots of leeway of recording the checkin times. Minutes if needs be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Answer:

*Use the `PropertiesService` to store the user's name to the script's properties and then run the function `logUser()` after you have returned to Slack.*

#### More Information:

You can store information directly as a script property and then use this in your `logUser()` function to log the users in. It will require a little reworking of your current code but the bsaic run down will be as follows:

- On POST, store the `userId` as a script property
- Set a time-based trigger to run `logUser()` in an unspecified amount of time in the future
- Return your content to Slack

Then on trigger of `logUser()`:

- Grab the current Script Properties
- Go through each one individually and log them to the sheet
- Delete the property after the user has been logged.

#### Code:

Firstly in your `doPost()`:

```js
function doPost(request){
  var params = request.parameters;
  var user = params.user_id;
  var text = params.text;

  if(text == ''){
    PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty(user, "logged-in");
    ScriptApp.newTrigger("logUser").timeBased().after(200).create();
      
    return ContentService.createTextOutput(':white_check_mark: Checked In! Thank you! <@' + user + '> ');
  } 
}
```

Then for your `logUser()` function:

```js
function logUser(){
  var checkinSheet = getTodaySheet();
  var usersToLogIn = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getKeys();
  var date = new Date();
  var time = date.getTime();

  usersToLogIn.forEach(function(user) {
    var name = getNameFromId(user);
    checkinSheet.appendRow([name, user[0], "TRUE"]);
    PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().deleteProperty(user);
  });  
}
```

#### References:

- [Class PropertiesService | Apps Script | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service)